# How do I fix these weird "edges" when using subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

Im modelling a guitar body but when I use subdivision surface I get these weird edges when I do. Is there an easy way to fix this or what can I do differently?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello there's a problem with your topology, please share your file